# Reading Data in SQLite-net

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, unity-game-engine, sqlite-net

I have recently started a new project that uses [SQLite4Unity3D](https://github.com/codecoding/SQLite4Unity3d) which also uses [SQLite-Net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net). I started using this after watching some videos and working with SQLite and everything was working fine on the in the Unity Editor then I decided to test it on android and found out it wouldn't work so after a bit of searching I came across SQLite4Unity3D which did work with android. I have the writing to database part down but can't figure out how to read it and put it into a list. The code I used before was(**This Code Works There is nothing wrong with it.**)

```
private void ShowLogs() {
       GetTables();
    for(int i = 0; i < LogDates.Count; i++)
    {

        GameObject tempObjec = Instantiate(ListPrefab.gameObject);
        LogDate tempList = LogDates[i];

        tempObjec.GetComponent<LogdateScript>().SetList(tempList.Date, tempList.Name, tempList.ID, tempList.Section);

        tempObjec.transform.SetParent(CloneParrent);
    }
}
private void GetTables()
{



LogDates.Clear(); 
        using (SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new 
SQLiteConnection(DatabaseName))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            using (IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                string sqlQuery = "SELECT *FROM WorkLog";

                dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

                using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        LogDates.Add(new LogDate(reader.GetString(0), 
reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(2)));

                    }
                    //TestText.text = reader.GetString(1);
                    dbConnection.Close();
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }  
}
```

And this was working fine in windows but not in android. **I want to know is there a way to recreate this using SQLite4Unity3d?** I can grab data from a table and output it but it I don't know how to put it into a list like I did in the code above.

```
public IEnumerable<LogDate> GetTable()
{
    return _connection.Table<LogDate>();

}
```

Comment: What statement failed.  Is the issue connecting to the database or something else?

Comment: Just saying "it doesn't work" doesn't give us anything to work with.

Comment: Can you SQL statement run with *FROM instead of * FROM ?

Comment: @jdweng  I'm sorry for the misunderstanding the code above works without a problem but that was with sqlite3. Now that i have switched to using sqlite4unity3d i cannot seem to find a way to rewrite it. I was wondering if anyone has worked with sqlite4unity3d and knows how to do this with it.

Comment: Looks like a typo like Josh pointed out. Isn't there an error in the Unity console window? If it isn't giving info, put some Debug.Log lines at each step to see where it's failing.

Comment: @dubbreak Like i said in my comment the code above had nothing wrong with it. It worked, but i need a way to make it work using the  SQLite4Unity3D plugin which does not use the same code as just plane SQLite3. So there is no IDataReader that i can use in the new code and am wondering if anyone who has used SQLite4Unity3d knows a workaround for it. I know how to grab that whole table but dont know how to get it list out like i had it before.`public IEnumerable<LogDate> GetTable()
    {
        return _connection.Table<LogDate>();

    }` This grabs everything without organizing.

Comment: @BimBimSalaBim Did you find a way to do it with SQLite4Unity3D? I've been stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @Nandgopal haha nope! I gave up doing it in unity just did the whole project in Java.